# Ionic 4 - Keyboard covers the input field inside a form

Tags: ionic-framework, keyboard, cordova-plugins, ionic4, ionic-native

In Android the keyboard covers the input field inside a form, thus making me unable to see what has been written unless I close the keyboard.

I'm not developing iOS, so can't say about that

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please share little bit more information regarding the same? like is it happening throughout the app or for a specific form only?

Comment: @MilanManwar Yes it is having throughout the app. I Have also open this issue on github https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/issues/110. You can check this for code and screenshots

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/issues/110#issuecomment-526556426 this works for me